# 100% Nav bar with transparent pngs for ends and repeating pattern

Tags: javascript, nav

I am trying to create a nav bar that will extend 100% width of the page and use 3 separate pngs for the background. 2 pngs will be for the edges, the other will be a repeating pattern in the background. I am completely stumped on how to do this. I can't absolutely position the edges in separate divs because they are transparent and would then overlap with the already transparent repeating pattern. I cant add a bg color to the divs either because you need to be able to see the content below.

Any help would be great.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways to achieve this. Here is an example using margins and floats to setup a DIV structure to work off of:

http://jsfiddle.net/LKLQx/